# dns lookup specified in /etc/hosts and then dscacheutil != differ from dig, host, chrome

Tags: dns, hosts

Via a long chain up of OS upgrades I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Setting entries in my /etc/hosts file is working only occasionally, mostly not.

For example on a freshly rebooted machine.  With the only networking set to Wifi.

Everything is unmodified and fine:

```
bash-3.2$ grep facebook.com /etc/hosts
# 127.0.0.1 facebook.com
bash-3.2$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
bash-3.2$ dscacheutil -q host -a name facebook.com
name: facebook.com
ipv6_address: 2a03:2880:f127:283:face:b00c::25de

name: facebook.com
ip_address: 157.240.18.35

bash-3.2$ host facebook.com
facebook.com has address 157.240.18.35
facebook.com has IPv6 address 2a03:2880:f127:283:face:b00c::25de
facebook.com mail is handled by 10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com.
```

But then I uncomment that line for facebook, and I get this:

```
bash-3.2$ grep facebook /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   facebook.com
bash-3.2$ sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
bash-3.2$ dscacheutil -q host -a name facebook.com
name: facebook.com
ipv6_address: 2a03:2880:f127:283:face:b00c::25de

name: facebook.com
ip_address: 127.0.0.1

bash-3.2$ host facebook.com
facebook.com has address 157.240.18.35
facebook.com has IPv6 address 2a03:2880:f127:283:face:b00c::25de
facebook.com mail is handled by 10 msgin.vvv.facebook.com.
```

I don't observe anything suspicious in the output of `scutil --dns`.  The `dig` command and `chrome` both seem immune to the /etc/hosts change.

help?

Comment: host, dig and Google Chrome don't proceed along the common macOS DNS resolution path - so there is nothing wrong with your result...

Answer (score 1):

This command will tell you which process is making the changes to your hosts file:

```
sudo dtrace -qn 'syscall::open*:entry /arg1&3/ { printf("%d %s %s\n", pid, execname, copyinstr(arg0)); }' | grep hosts
```

Comment: Very cool trick.  But, I have no reason to suspect anybody is modifying my /etc/host files, except me.  The problem is that my edits are not propagating to all the actors who query dns.